# How to retrieve all user's display name from Azure Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Sorry I'm still new to Azure AD. I want to retrieve all user's display name from Azure Active Directory and populate it into a dropdownlistFor/dropdownlist but I have no idea how to get it.

Currently I only know how to get the current logged in user's display name using

```
@using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
@model User
@Model.DisplayName
```

I've also tried to look at Azure's github https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web but cloning it only gives me build errors

Any help or code example will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: how do you call that API, I tried their code example but it's not working

Answer (score 1):

In order to get information about a tenant, you must query the AAD Graph API. The AAD Graph API is a REST API which allows you to query all the data that the directory stores, such as the users in a tenant.

The best way to get started with a simple query like this is to try it out using the [Graph Explorer](https://graphexplorer.cloudapp.net/Home/Index/DemoCompany?UrlRequest=GET&text=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.windows.net%2Fgraphdir1.onmicrosoft.com%2Fusers).

Note in the query I linked above, I use the demo tenant the explorer provides. You can also sign into your own tenant and repeat the query.

Once you understand what the query looks like, and what you should expect as a response, you should then look at [our samples](https://github.com/azure-samples?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=graph&type=&language=) which already query the Graph API, and can be modified for your needs.

I see that you have linked to one above which resulted in build errors. My suggestion is to file a bug report with the details of your error, and try another sample in the meantime!

Note that moving forward, we are looking to push all of our traffic through the Microsoft Graph, which acts as a front end for the AAD Graph API and some of our other big Office 365 APIs. If you are looking to stay ahead of the game here, you should try building your app against our Microsoft Graph. Details [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/).

Let me know if this helps!